# using google excel, how do I take a list of numbers and make closely equal groups of a known number

Tags: google-workspace

Up to 21 different numbers in a entered list. I need to generate (based on number of entries
equal groups of numerical totals.

example: Monday golf players (not always the same) but today.....13...
Each player when signing in enters his "points" (never less than 8 or more than 36)
Number of teams are decided with even groups, extra players are dropped.
So we make 3 groups x 4 players..dropping 1 player, but total number of players per group is limited to 5.
so: 14 players would be 3 groups of 4, 2 dropped,
9 = 3 of 3, 10 =2 of 5, 11 = 2 of 5 drop 1, 12 = 3 x 4, 14 = 3 x 4 drop 2, etc.
we never have more than 21 players.....

Here's the problem: points are entered randomly. So I end up with a list of 13 different numbers
in a random order. I need to make 3 groups of 4, with each group having very close totals. EX:
9,11.8.5,20,13,18,10,16,9,15,11,(21),7. I manually drop largest (21), make groups from remaining.  Results looking for: 3 groups of 4, group A. 9,11,8.5,20 (49)  B.13,18,10,7 (48) C.16,9,15,11 (51)...

Mike Strange